# Línea defectuosa al ajustar polinomio cuadrático a datos no lineales

Tags: r

Estoy intentando ajustar un polinomio cuadrático a mis datos usando el siguiente código:

```
#Polynimial regression for y ~ x
model <- lm(y ~ x + I(x^2))
summary(model)

#Box and whisker plot + polynomial
boxplot(y ~ x,
        col=c("white","lightgray"), ylab= "y", xlab= "x", dat)
means <- tapply(y,x,mean)
points(means,col="red",pch=18)
predicted.intervals <- predict(model,data.frame(x=x),interval='confidence',
                               level=0.99)
lines(x,predicted.intervals[,1],col='green',lwd=3)
lines(x,predicted.intervals[,2],col='black',lwd=1)
lines(x,predicted.intervals[,3],col='black',lwd=1)
```

[Enlace a datos](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wnje518qyaovuo1/yourfile.csv?dl=0)

[Enlace datos B](https://www.dropbox.com/s/f7994feit6bly3n/datos.csv?dl=0)

El caso es que cuando corro el programa me aparece el gráfico de cajas, los puntos rojos representando las medias y la línea verde del polinomio ajustado a los datos. No obstante, también aparece una extraña línea recta que une las medias de los niveles 1 y 11 que no tengo ni idea de dónde proviene. Aquí va el gráfico:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He ajustado más veces polinomios a mis datos en regresiones no lineales, pero esto nunca me había pasado.

¿Alguna solución?

**Edición 1:**

Gráfico obtenido con datos B.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Finalmente, he conseguido ajustar el polinomio a los datos. El código utilizado es el siguiente:

```
#Factorizo la variable x
x <- as.factor(x)
#Vuelvo a transformar la variable a numérica
x <- as.numeric(x)

#Regresión cuadrática
model <- lm(y ~ x + I(x^2))
summary(model)

#Ajuste del polinomio
boxplot(y ~ x,
        col=c("white","lightgray"), ylab= "y", xlab= "x", dat)
means <- tapply(y,x,mean)
points(means,col="red",pch=18)
predicted.intervals <- predict(model,data.frame(x=x),interval='confidence',
                               level=0.99)
lines(x,predicted.intervals[,1],col='green',lwd=3)
```

El resultado para los datos B es este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No obstante, me quedan algunas dudas:

Mi variable x comprende valores de 0 a 1 (11 niveles en pasos de 0.1)

1. ¿Por qué he tenido que factorizar mi variable original x, después volver a transformar la variable a numérica (adoptando esta valores discretos entre 0 y 11? Solo así consigo ajustar el polinomio a los datos, pero la regresión está ejecutada sobre valores numéricos de 1 a 11.
2. ¿Por qué en el caso del "conjunto de datos B" debo utilizar

   lines(x,predicted.intervals[,1],col='green',lwd=3)

... mientras que en el caso del "conjunto de datos A" debo utilizar

```
lines(predicted.intervals[,1],col='green',lwd=3)
```

?

Comment: pyring, podrías añadir los datos que generan la gráfica? si no son demasiado grandes puedes hacer `dput(x)` y `dput(y)` y agregar esa salida a tu pregunta. Saludos.

Comment: hola @Patricio Moracho. El problema es que el conjunto de datos es enorme (son datos de simulaciones): 100000 valores cada variable.

Comment: Te entiendo, pero al menos yo, sin ver los datos me cuesta entender que es lo que puede estar pasando.  Si se me ocurre algo te comento.

Comment: No tendría inconveniente en compartir un archivo csv. Creo que una posibilidad sería por medio del chat de stackoverflow. Un saludo.

Comment: No tengo mucho experiencia en el chat, pero si quieres lo intentamos, aunque sin no tienes algún problema de confidencialidad con los datos, tal vez lo mejor es algún dropbox o similar y un enlace en la pregunta así incluso tienes mas chances de respuesta. Saludos

Comment: Sin problema, he compartido un enlace a los datos. Gracias.

Comment: Posiblemente el problema es que `x` debiera ser un Factor, prueba antes que nada `x <- as.factor(x)` y cualquier cosa nos cuentas. saludos.

Comment: Es curioso que con los datos A (tomando las variables como numéricas) obtengo un modelo de regresión cuadrática sin problema. Con los datos B aparece solo esta línea recta extraña. He factorizado x antes de realizar la regresión lineal y obtengo un error: Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
  contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
In addition: Warning message:
In Ops.factor(x, 2) : ‘^’ not meaningful for factors

Comment: Prueba algo como esto: `lines(spline(factor(x), fitted),col='green',lwd=3)` esto debiera funcionarte en ambos casos. si es así, reedito la respuesta.

Comment: Muchas Gracias. Esta opción me seguía dando error. Finalmente, he encontrado una solución pero me siguen quedando muchas dudas... He editado la pregunta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vamos al primer problema, los datos del [conjunto A](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wnje518qyaovuo1/yourfile.csv?dl=0). Voy a trabajar solo con la regresión, veamos:

```
datA <- read.table(file = "datA.csv", header = T, sep=",", stringsAsFactors = F, dec = ".")

model <- lm(datA$y ~ datA$x + I(datA$x^2))
datA$fitted <- predict(model,data.frame(x=datA$x))
```

Ahora vamos a graficar solo los puntos y la curva para la regresión:

```
plot(datA$x, datA$fitted)
lines(datA$x, datA$fitted)
```

El resultado seguramente te es conocido:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto es explicable por que `datA` no está ordenada por `x`, al dibujar las lineas a partir de los puntos `x` y `fitted` eventualmente podríamos tener un punto `(1, ?)` y luego un `(0, ?)`, por lo que volveríamos al origen haciendo que la gráfica sea "circular". Para resolver esto, simplemente ordenamos por `x`:

```
datA.ordered <- datA[order(datA$x),]

plot(datA.ordered$x, datA.ordered$fitted)
lines(datA.ordered$x, datA.ordered$fitted)
```

Ahora el resultado es más acorde a lo buscado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Es esta la solución y explicación del problema? Sí y No. Veamos, si incorporamos está gráfica al `boxplot`

```
datA <- read.table(file = "C:/Users/pmoracho/Downloads/datA.csv", header = T, sep=",", stringsAsFactors = F, dec = ".")

model <- lm(datA$y ~ datA$x + I(datA$x^2))
boxplot(datA$y ~ datA$x,
        col=c("white","lightgray"), ylab= "y", xlab= "x", datA)

means <- tapply(datA$y,datA$x,mean)
points(means,col="red",pch=18)
datA$fitted <- predict(model,data.frame(x=datA$x))
datA.ordered <- datA[order(datA$x),]
lines(datA.ordered$x, datA.ordered$fitted,col='green',lwd=3)
```

podemos ver este resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Qué podemos notar? la curva original se "comprimió" entre los valores de 0 y 1, 
la explicación es que no son compatibles los sistemas de coordenadas, esto por que el `boxplot` considera los valores de `x` como variables discretas, sin embargo nuestros valores de `datA$x` no lo son, y aquí es dónde entra el uso de `factor()`, así:

```
lines(factor(datA.ordered$x), datA.ordered$fitted,col='green',lwd=3)
```

Ahora sí los datos de `x` son consistentes con las `x` del `boxplot`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto explica y me ha funcionado para los dos juegos de datos, no publico los resultados para no hacer más larga la respuesta. De todas formas te preguntarás por que originalmente han sido distintos los comportamientos de los dos juegos de datos, la explicación es sencilla, el conjunto A está desordenado y el B está ordenado (siempre hablando del valor de `x`).

Te recomiendo además que uses `spline()` para dibujar estas curvas, te evitaría tener que ordenar previamente y la otra ventaja más importante es que no le pasa a `line()` el juego completo de datos sino los puntos mínimos para interporlar la línea en la gráfica:

```
lines(spline(factor(datA$x), datA$fitted),col='green',lwd=3)
```

Comment: Gracias @Patricio Moracho. ¿Llegas a ver por qué con unos datos diferentes y utilizando el mismo código, no se consigue una línea ajustada a los datos sino una extraña línea recta? He añadido enlace a datos B.

Comment: He añadido también el gráfico obtenido con el mismo código para datos B.

Comment: @pyring, rehíce completamente la respuesta, ahora creo que está la explicación del problema, antes solo teníamos soluciones parciales.

Comment: Fenómeno, de gran ayuda.